# selecting rows from database based on specific character in a column

Tags: mysql, select, substr

I've got a problem with `SELECT`ing stuff from a `MySQL` database based on a specific character in a specific column. This column contains a string with 1s and 0s. Example string:
`0101000000`.

I need to `SELECT` only the rows which look something like this (X is wildcard): `X1X1X0XXXX`

How do I do this with a `SELECT` query? I'm sure it isn't that hard.

Sincerly,

Axel Latvala

Comment: You can see character replace for single character in google easily.  Wild card for any character is Underscore("_").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this col is a string then you should be able to match rows with:

```
myRow LIKE '_1_1_0____'
```

if it's just 0 and 1 that you're storing (it's binary) then you should probably cast it to an `INT` and use bit masks to query the table. This method would use far less storage space and be far faster, it'd be more complicated to implement though.

MySQL's pattern matching doc: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/pattern-matching.html

Comment: no problem. Worth noting that I don't think there's any way for MySQL to use an index for this query so it won't be fast if you end up with hundreds of thousands or millions of rows.